# Why is a branched alkane more stable than the straight-chain isomer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

My text book says that branched alkanes are more stable than their straight-chain isomers, but does not give any explanation.
Is this merely a fact, or something that can be logically rationalized ?

A thermodynamic cycle is welcomed, and an intuitive clarification is even better.

Comment: Maybe thinking in terms of entropy might help?

Comment: See these posts: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153936/why-is-the-enthalpy-of-formation-of-2-2-dimethylpentane-larger-than-that-of-2-2 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139763/why-are-branched-alkanes-used-as-fuels-instead-of-straight-chain-alkanes ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80324/why-the-boiling-and-melting-points-of-n-alkanes-are-higher-than-those-of-iso-or ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42426/standard-enthalpy-of-formation-for-branched-alkanes

Comment: See this also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/123093/deciding-the-order-of-heat-of-combustion-of-isomeric-alkanes/130811#130811

Comment: More stable in what respect?